# What does the word "warmth" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I am not sure about the meaning of the word "warmth" in the following sentence:

> If you think that ML Enhance makes a sunset’s glow look too much like daylight,
>   you can move the Temperature slider to the right to
>   restore some warmth. (The sentence is not available online.)

Are the words "glow" and "warmth" synonyms here and do both of them simply mean "glowing effect" ([sense 3 here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/warmth)) in this context?

Here is a brief description of the ML Enhance feature:

> The machine learning-powered ML Enhance intelligently fine-tunes 37
>   individual color adjustments to give you the best starting point for
>   making your own creative edits to a photo. Trained on over 20 million
>   professional photos and integrated via Core ML 2, ML Enhance makes
>   adjustments based on the actual contents of a photo, taking care of
>   all the little details that go into a great photo, such as white
>   balance, exposure, shadow, and highlight detail, and leaves the
>   creative finishing touches to you.

Any suggestions or inputs?

Comment: input is singular. Warmth is warmth. It has no "other" meaning.

Comment: @Lambie Wiktionary has four definitions of [warmth](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/warmth) (1. heat; 2. friendliness; 3. intensity; 4. red and yellow colours). Once you've found the meaning you want, it has three other meanings.

Comment: @CJDennis How funny, they all apply in this case.

Comment: @Lambie I doubt the software can make the image hot to the touch, emotionally intense, or friendly. It could increase the reds and yellows of the image.

Comment: @CJDennis A warmer image is more friendly and more intense emotionally for a viewer. The OP should have tried it in his/her own language.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*Warmth*, in photography, image editing, or other graphic arts, describes the amount of red, yellow, and orange shades, as opposed to blues, greens and teals.

Look at the labels on this color wheel:

[image: color wheel]

This photography site provides good information, and helpful images: "
[Warm and Cold Light (White Balance)"](https://brentmailphotography.com/portrait-model/warm-and-cold-light.html)

> Have you ever seen the sun set? What colour was the light when it set, did you notice the wonderful reds, and yellows? How about a camp fire? That is warm light.

Comment: This is true in any pictorial domain. Painting and drawing, too.

Comment: @Lambie, I agree, but I couldn't think of a good word to encompass all, or the relevant visual arts.  If you've got a suggestion, I'd like to hear it (or go ahead and edit).

Comment: I am in no way objecting to your answer. I am merely saying that the word warmth with regard to color holds true to painting and drawing as well. There is no better word. :)